# System.Text.Json - How to deserialize immutable objects with ReferenceHandler.Preserve?

Tags: c#, json, .net-5, system.text.json

I found out how to use System.Text.Json with immutable objects using the [JsonConstructor] attribute (see: [How to use immutable types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-immutability?pivots=dotnet-5-0)), and separately how to [preserve references](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-preserve-references?pivots=dotnet-5-0) with .Net 5.

Unfortunately, when trying to combine the 2, the following error apears:

> NotSupportedException
> Reference metadata is not honored when deserializing types using parameterized constructors.

According to the first [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-immutability?pivots=dotnet-5-0), this is to be expected:

> This feature can't be used to preserve value types or immutable types.
> On deserialization, the instance of an immutable type is created after
> the entire payload is read. So it would be impossible to deserialize
> the same instance if a reference to it appears within the JSON
> payload.

Deserializing does seem to work with Newtonsoft.Json though (even when serializing with System.Text.Json).

Is there any other way to make deserializing work with System.Text.Json as well?

Comment: Do you have json payload and .net types? According to dotnet sources something is wrong with using constructor, but simple preserve reference for a record with two same class fields works fine, so the issue happens on some specific composition.

Comment: Preserving references with immutable objects -- or any object with a parameterized constructor -- doesn't work with Json.NET either. From the [docs](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PreserveObjectReferences.htm#PreserveReferencesHandling): *References cannot be preserved when a value is set via a non-default constructor. With a non-default constructor, child values must be created before the parent value so they can be passed into the constructor, making tracking reference impossible.*  The difference is, Json.NET ignores the setting while System.Text.Json throws an exception.